# Flutter string space showing + in email

Tags: flutter, dart

I am simply open email app from URL Launcher like this

```
      final Uri _emailLaunchUri = Uri(
          scheme: 'mailto',
          path: 'sales.igidrive@igi.com.pk',
          queryParameters: {
            'subject': 'IGIDRIVE SALE - ${userName} - ${userNumber}'
          }
      );
      launch(_emailLaunchUri.toString());
```

When its opening in email its showing subject like `IGIDRIVE+SALE+-+UMAIZ+KHAN+-+-923123131`

Mean when space comes its replace space with + sign how can i give space then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRy this

```
final Uri _emailLaunchUri = Uri(
          scheme: 'mailto',
          path: 'sales.igidrive@igi.com.pk',
         query: 'subject=GIDRIVE SALE - ${userName} - ${userNumber}&body=My Message Body'
      );
      launch(_emailLaunchUri.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

> result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WzRJ.png

```
  String string = 'IGIDRIVE SALE - USERNAME - USERNUMBER';
  String result = string.replaceAll(' ', '+');
  print(result);
```